# Git Revert On Remote

Tags: git

I am new to Git and using WebStorm to push and pull my code. We are working on a common project. Lat night my friend updated some code and pushed the changes.

Today I pulled the code and merged the changes and by mistake I kept my changes and discarded the changes offered by pull request. And then pushed these changes on git remote..

So basically now what I want is to :

1. Revert back to the previous state on local i.e. the state before pull request and also on remote I want the same state as of last night i.e. before push request.

So, this is what I want to do :

1. Revert on remote to previous version.
2. Pull the code again.
3. Do the merge.
4. Push the new code.

So right now on Remote I have :

- My friend code version commit,
- Then my wrong version commit that doesn't include the merge of previous code commit,
- And if i follow below answers of reverting back on local and then push then I would have my new revert code version commit. But at last I want on remote 1 + 3.

Lets see this mathematically

- X= Local State where I opened my computer and changed the code and
  committed.
- Y= Remote State where my friend made changed on his local computer and pushed to remote last night.
- Z= Remote State when I pulled my friend code and started merging but did some mistake and discarded change by my friend and then committed and pushed the code which is basically state x to remote.

So, basically

- on my local I have state Z.
- on remote I have state Z
- on my friend local state Y.

> I want on remote X + Y.

Comment: You cannot "push the unmerged code". Only committed code can be pushed. It is unclear from your question exactly what happened. Without knowing the exact sequence of unwanted git commands, and without knowing exactly how you expect to resolve the issue, an authoritative answer will not be possible.

Comment: What you basically do to clean up any of this mess (especially on a repo which is not used by others) is to cleaup your local branch. You can reset to an older version and cherry pick the changes you want to keep. Once your branch looks fine your force push. This will modify history but it will also clean up traces of your shame. If someone (build server) checks out this branch you might wipe/purge the workspace and start over.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Hi sam I think I did some mistake and during merge phase I only kept my code and hence it pushed the merged code done by me which didn't included the pulled code changes.

Comment: This is still a vague description that lacks any specifics. Without seeing specific logs of all commands executed, only a vague answer is possible: undo all your changes in your local branch, then push it to the remote, using `--force`, if necessary. That's it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Hi sam is the question clear now.

Comment: A safer course that achieves the same result would be to pull (now local == remote, has your wrong commits and doesn't have other correct commits), revert the wrong commit and push (now local == remote, doesn't have your wrong commit but also doesn't have other correct commits), then `git cherry-pick` the right commit from master's history.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to revert a commit you can use this command:

```
git revert commit id goes here
```

Example:

```
git revert aa12bb34
```

This is what [revert](http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.html) does:

> Reverting a commit means to create a new commit that undoes all
>   changes that were made in the bad commit. Just like above, the bad
>   commit remains there, but it no longer affects the the current master
>   and any future commits on top of it.

Comment: But this command will only make change on local right. As the code i am working is shared space, I want to revert back on remote so that every body see previous version.

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary This should work for remote, not just local.

Comment: I think if you need this on the remote, then after your "revert" you need to push the new set of commits to the remote with `git push`.  Since the revert commit is just a reverse of the original commit, you probably won't have to force push.

Comment: @mrrogers but then that will again overwrite the remote right. I have to merge again with previous git code

Comment: Yes, you'll be rolling forward. Is this not what you want to do? It is what I'd recommend doing.

Comment: i agree with @paulhicks (and of course @Harrison).  But you're not really "overriding" remote as much as you are adding to it's history.  it's the right thing to do and it'll accomplish what you want which is updating that branch with the right stuff.  and you can always unwind it if you need since each commit is stored separately.

Comment: @mrrogers I got what you are saying but my question is when you revert back and push the code. How I am going to merge it with the code uploded by my friend last night. As the reverted code is same as the code I want to push after merging it with the pulled code committed by my friend.

Comment: so basically on remote it wil be my friend code version commit, then my wrong version commit that doest include the merge of previous code commit, and  then my new revert code version commit.

Comment: you should pull the remote branch before you apply your revert commit.  So pull the stuff your friend did.  `git revert <my commit sha>`.  then push it back up.  i think that should do it.  when your friend does his/her work, she'll have to pull the branch again and will get your new reverted code.  does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your partial description, it seems unlikely that you used any of the "dangerous" options, and you simply added and pushed a bad commit to the remote.

Assuming that the remote repository is "origin", and the branch in question is "master":

```
git log origin/master
```

This should give you the log of the commits on the remote. You should see your bad merge, followed by the previous commits on the remote branch.

Before you start trying to repair this, fork off a new branch, as a means of tagging your current tip, as an insurance policy. If you mess up, you can easily return to your commit commit on the tip:

```
git checkout -b master-before-i-tried-to-fix-this-mess
```

Now, take the commit hash before the merge, and first, do a non-destructive checkout:

```
git checkout <hash>
```

Where `<hash>` is the hash of the immediately preceding commit before your bad merge.

Now look in your directory. Convince yourself that this was the tip of the remote branch before it got messed up.

Then, return back to your local branch:

```
git checkout master
```

Now, force-reset your master branch to the good commit:

```
git reset --hard <hash>
```

Now, you should be back in the state right before you executed the merge. Now try to do the merge again:

```
git merge whatever-you-tried-to-merge
```

Once you convinced yourself that you merged everything correctly:

```
git push --force
```

You really need to make sure that you're pushing a good remote branch, and if anyone else has the remote repository checked out, you'll need to inform them of what you did.

It is possible to push your fixed remote as an ordinary commit, but that would require more work, and would actually be a more dangerous procedure. You'll just have to take your lumps, and use this as a learning experience.

If you discover that you messed up again, you will need to delete your local master branch, and use your insurance policy to recreate it:

```
git checkout master-before-i-tried-to-fix-this-mess
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master
```

Then try again.

Comment: Now, you should be back in the state right before you executed the merge. Now try to do the merge again:

git merge whatever-you-tried-to-merge ;  Before this I don't have to pull the previous code then only I can merge.

Comment: What I mean is 
git reset --hard <hash>
this command will only locally revert back to previous commit. Now to merge with last night code, I have to revert on remote also. So that when I pull again I can merge both the code.

Comment: The only way to revert on the remote is to push the fix from your local branch. There is no "revert on the remote" in git. If you do not use feature branches, and you just commit your changes on master, cowboy-style, and just pull in order to merge, then you're asking for trouble. You should be using feature branches, which you then merge back to master. That would make it easier to fix mistakes like these. Now, your only option is to go look through your reflog, try to fetch bits and piece of your previous work, commit it, and push it again.

Comment: Or, alternatively, you could do a reset --hard back to the last commit on your local branch before you pulled in order to merge, then pull again, and this time do the merge correctly.

Comment: Yeah I want to do the OR version but again when u pull its the code that I committed and uploaded which is same as revert back. And yeah I learnt my lesson now onwards i will work on feature branches.

Comment: What you can do is basically use the approach that I suggested on a different branch. Get that branch to look like the merge should've looked. Then, use "git diff work-branch..master" to generate a diff between that branch and master, then "git apply" the diff to master, making it look exactly like your work branch, then push the end result.