# Git revert on remote branch

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-revert

There is an [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239533/git-revert-on-remote) like my problem. But I want to describe my problem.

X: good head
Y: current head with unwanted commits

Y = y1 + y2 + ..... + yn

I want to do this: Z = X + y3 ... + yn. yi comes from some sub-branches and merging.To create Z, I find commit id of X. I run below code :

```
git checkout -b newBranch COMMIT_X_ID
git merge some_branch
git push
```

On bitbucket, I merge Z with Y. This is totally wrong. New version, includes all commits. I understand why. How can I revert remote repo with saving some existing commits?

Comment: What’s a sub-branch?

Comment: It does sound like you want to rebase.

Comment: @evolutionxbox somebranch includes some development. (yx comes from somebranch, it is merged in Y)

Comment: `git push origin commitID:Y ` Is this true solution?

Comment: If you don't have too many yi's  then you can cherry-pick each one so that the commit history is neat.

Comment: Finally, I undo changes manually for y3. I add a new commit. It is enough solution for me.